# Remove first empty line from a file

Tags: powershell

I have a string like:

```
$FileContent = "
    InstallMode = $InstallMode
    Logfile = $Logfile
    Silent = y
"
```

Then I remove unwanted white-space and write to file:

```
$FileContent = $FileContent.Replace(" ","")
New-Item C:\Test.ini -Type File -Value $FileContent
```

There is still white space at the start of the file. A solution is:

```
$FileContent = " InstallMode = $InstallMode
    Logfile = $Logfile
    Silent = y
"
```

But this is an ugly fix and makes the code look poorly formatted. Is there a better way to remove first empty line from file?

Comment: use the `.Trim()` function. Without parameters it cuts of all whitespace characters at the beginning and the end of the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered adding a `Trim` before the `Replace` - like this:

```
$FileContent = $FileContent.Trim().Replace(" ","")
```

`Trim` removes leading and trailing white space. There is also a `TrimStart` and `TrimEnd` if you only want to remove one or the other.

Comment: You could also `Trim` the string after the `Replace`.

Comment: Yes. The result would be the same.

Answer (score 1):

The first character is not actually a space but carriage return (13 in ASCII) and another one is new line (10 in ASCII). You can check this using that formula:

```
[int[]][char[]]$FileContent
```

You should receive something like (list of ASCII number for all the characters in the string):

```
13
10
32
32
32
32
73
```

If you want to trim this you can just use `$FileContent.Substring(2)` which will remove first two characters.

[Here](https://www.asciitable.com/) you can check all the characters and their ASCII codes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [here-string](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2012/02/14/powershell-here-string.aspx), they can be used to declare multi-line strings.

As the string content must be on the next line to the `@"` it is displayed as you wish but does not contain a line break at the start.

This would remove the need for using `Trim`, and your existing `Replace` would still function as is.

```
$FileContent = @"
    InstallMode = $InstallMode
    Logfile = $Logfile
    Silent = y
"@
```

Answer (score 0):

If the variable `$Logfile` represents a path containing spaces your `.Replace(" ","")` method would remove those also.

So I suggest using the RegEx based `-Replace` operator which can anchor at line begin `^`
(The empty replacement part can be omitted)

```
## Q:\Test\2018\06\11\SO_50794799.ps1
$InstallMode = "doesn't matter"
$LogFile = '"C:\Program Files (x86)\_Tools\"'

$FileContent = @"
    InstallMode = $InstallMode
    Logfile = $Logfile
    Silent = y
"@

$FileContent = $FileContent -Replace "(?sm)^\s+" -Replace ' = ','='
New-Item C:\Test.ini -Type File -Value $FileContent
```

---

```
InstallMode=doesn't matter
Logfile="C:\Program Files (x86)\_Tools\"
Silent=y
```